# How to write and read a struct which contains another struct in C?

Tags: c

Here is my structs:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char* description;
    char* alternativeAnswer[4];
    int rightAnswer;
}question;

typedef struct 
{
    question** questions;
    int size;
    int max;
}questionList;
```

I want to save a `questionList` to a file and then read from it.
But if I write in this way:

```
fwrite(a_questionList,sizeof(questionList),1,outfile);
```

and read in this way:

```
fread(newQuestionList,sizeof(questionList),1,infile);
```

I find that only `size` and `max` are saved and read successfully.So how to save and read `questions`?
Thank you!

Comment: Oh, `questions` is saved and read successfully, but `questions` is just a pointer, and the thing it points to doesn't get saved and read.

Comment: Have another call where you fwrite the list separately, followed by fwrite'ing the two variables. Similar for fread. Something like myfread and myfwrite...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, as mentioned in a comment, this does not work due to the fact that you are using pointers for the question list.  For the char strings the program will read characters until a `\0` is found.  But for anything else, only the value of the pointer variable will be written; that is, just the memory address.

(By the way, it is a bit strange that you use a double pointer for a list of questions.  I will assume that this is a mistake, and you meant `question * questions`.)

My recommendation is to write, for each structure, a `write_<structure>` function, and use those for internal components in the functions of more external ones, following the structures' hierarchy from inside out.  Here you have only one level of indirection, and only one list of items, but this approach can be very useful for a multilevel, multilists problem.

Note, however, that since you are using pointers, you will end up having to pre-allocate them at reading time.  And, since you did not specify the length of those strings at declaration time (you can allocate 10 or 10000 chars for the same pointer), you will not know how many characters to read for each string.  For this reason, I would also use predefined maximum lengths for the char strings; otherwise, you will end up having to pre-allocate them at reading time.  Doing so, in addition, you can write the entire structure at once.  The declarations would look like this:

```
#define NUM_OF_QUESTIONS    10
#define MAX_STRING_LEN     256
#define NUM_OF_ALT_ANSWERS   4

typedef struct {
    char description[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    char alternativeAnswer[NUM_OF_ALT_ANSWERS][MAX_STRING_LEN];
    int rightAnswer;
} question;

typedef struct  {
    question questions[NUM_OF_QUESTIONS];
    int size;
    int max;
} questionList;
```

Doing so, *you can now* use a single `fwrite` and a single `fread` to write and read in one single go the entire list of questions.  For this particular case, you will be done.

Note that I fixed the number of questions.  If you don't want to do this (that is if you still have `question * questions`), my recommendation is to use the former (more extensible) suggested approach, that is, having something like this:

```
int write_question(FILE * fHdl, question * q, int items) {
    return fwrite((void*)(q), sizeof(question), items, fHdl);
}

int write_questionList(FILE * fHdl, questionList * qList, int numOfQuestions) {
    int nBytes = write_question(fHdl, qList->questions, numOfQuestions);
    if (0 != nBytes) { 
        nBytes += fwrite((void*)(&(qList->size)), sizeof(int), 1, fHdl);
        nBytes += fwrite((void*)(&(qList->max)), sizeof(int), 1, fHdl);
    }
    return nBytes;
}
```

And the same for reading.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have two more questions.What does `nBytes` do?And is it necessary to coercion `q` ,`qList->size` and `qList->max` ?

Comment: The signature of the fwrite() function is `size_t
     fwrite(const void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, FILE *restrict stream);`;  it returns the number of bytes written.  That helps you to know if everything went well.  The variable nBytes just gets this numbers.  This is not used in the functions above, but you may want to check, after every write or at the end, if you wrote/read what was expected.
And fwrite/fread expect a (const) `void` pointer, so you simply cast it, so the compiler does not complain.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try something like this in your struct definitions

```
typedef struct 
{
    char* description;
    char* alternativeAnswer[4];
    int rightAnswer;
}question;

typedef struct 
{
    struct question* questions;
    int size;
    int max;
}questionList;
```

Consider the following sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student_college_detail
{
    int college_id;
    char college_name[50];
};

struct student_detail 
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float percentage;
    // structure within structure
    struct student_college_detail clg_data;
}stu_data;

int main() 
{
    struct student_detail stu_data = {1, "Alex", 90.5, 71145,
                                       "UCB"};
    FILE *outfile; 

    // open file for writing 
    outfile = fopen ("student_detail.dat", "w"); 
    if (outfile == NULL) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n"); 
        exit (1); 
    } 

    // stu_data to file 
    fwrite (&stu_data, sizeof(struct student_detail), 1, outfile); 

    if(fwrite != 0)  
        printf("contents to file written successfully !\n"); 
    else 
        printf("error writing file !\n"); 

    // close file 
    fclose (outfile); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `struct question* questions` and `question** questions`?